# What does"take our life as we might find it" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Mark Twain's "A Dog's Tale", there is a sentence like this,"said we were sent into this world for a wise and good purpose, and must do our duties without repining, **take our life as we might find it**, live it for the best good of others, and never mind about the results" What does "take our life" mean? Also, what does "it" in "find it" really mean? Apparently "it" refers to life, but what does "find life" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase means *accept the circumstances of our life*. *It* does refer to life. *As we might find it* means *as the events and things not in our control that make up our life occur, we need to accept them*.